# I get empty file from sliding window code?

Tags: python

Does anyone know why the coding below did not work? I want to change the sequence protein with label annotation intrinsically disordered protein. I was using sliding window code to make a peptide sequence and labeled it with 0,1 as an un-disordered and disordered sequence. But after running the code I got empty excel and fasta files. Here is the complete code. When I run the code to check the header of the data frame, it is said callable. What is exactly wrong with my code. Does anybody have a suggestion or another code to fix it?
Thank you

```
DATA_DIR = 'D:/TMU/spring semester/application of artficial intelligence in genomics/Project 7 - DeepDisoBind'
window_size = 5

def ws_generating(plist, label):
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Sequence', 'Label'])
for neg in plist:
    # Padding
    if neg < window_size:
        seq_result = '-'*(window_size-neg) + sseq[:neg+window_size+1]
        df = df.append({'Sequence': seq_result, 'Label':label}, ignore_index=True)
    elif neg > (len(sseq) - window_size):
        seq_result = sseq[neg-window_size:] + '-'*(window_size - (len(sseq) - neg) + 1)
        df = df.append({'Sequence': seq_result, 'Label':label}, ignore_index=True)
    else:
        seq_result = sseq[neg-window_size:neg+window_size+1]
        df = df.append({'Sequence': seq_result, 'Label':label}, ignore_index=True)
return df
f = open(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'Training_class.txt'), 'r')

fdata = f.read()

data = fdata.split('\n>')[1:]
df_final_result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Sequence', 'Label'])
for dt in data: 
sid = dt.fsplit('\n')[0]
sseq = dt.split('\n')[1]
smap = dt.split('\n')[2]

ppos = [pos for pos, char in enumerate(smap) if char == '1']
pneg = [neg for neg, char in enumerate(smap) if char == '0']

df_pos_result = ws_generating(ppos, 'Yes')
df_neg_result = ws_generating(pneg, 'No')

df_final_result = pd.concat([df_final_result, df_pos_result, df_neg_result])"
df_final_result.to_csv(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'trainrun.ws05.csv'), index=None)

df_final_result()
```